# Django Form Error: table main_manifest has no column named manifest_name

Tags: django, sqlite, django-models, django-forms

I've got a Django Form that appears correctly in my browser, but after filling out the fields and hitting submit, I get this error: `table main_manifest has no column named manifest_name`

I'm using Python 2.7.5 & Django 1.7.1, so I've run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py makemigrations 
python manage.py migrate
```

And I tried deleting my migrations and Database and have rebuilt my tables. **Why am I getting this error?**

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Manifest(models.Model):
    manifest_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    keywords = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Forms.py**

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Manifest

class ManifestForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Manifest
        fields = "__all__"
```

----Edit-----
Based on Paulo's comment I think I may have my file structure messed up and that why my migration commands are not working. Can someone verify that this looks correct?

```
MY_PROJECT_FOLDER
--__init__.py
--settings.py
--urls.py
--wsgi.py
MAIN_APP_FOLDER
--MIGRATIONS_FOLDER
--TEMPLATES_FOLDER
----__init__.py
----admin.py
----forms.py
----models.py
----views.py
----MAIN_APP_FOLDER
------allfiles.html
------morefiles.html
STATIC_FOLDER
TEMPLATES_FOLDER
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

----Edit-----
It's probably worth noting that after running `python manage.py sql main` in terminal I seem to see quite clearly that table main_manifest DOES actually have a column named manifest_name:

```
CREATE TABLE "main_manifest" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    "manifest_name" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    "keywords" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    "product_name" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
    "timestamp" datetime NOT NULL
)
;
```

Comment: This error often indicates the model definition is out of sync with the actual database table. If it is the case, you must run the appropriate "ALTER TABLE..." command or delete the table and run a "manage.py syncdb" (or "manage.py schemamigration ..." if you are using south).

Comment: my understanding is that migrations are now part of Django 1.7.1 (http://south.aeracode.org/) and that South is no longer needed, and I can instead just use: 
python manage.py syncdb 
python manage.py makemigrations  
python manage.py migrate 

After running the above commands is it still necessary to run the "alter table" command?

Comment: Sorry Michael, I failed to notice you are running 1.7. No, in theory it should be enough - but django is complaining the table lacks a "manifest_name" column, so perhaps you are not running the schemamigration on the right app or some other problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok It Turns out that I missed something that I definitely should have known. The migration commands require that i tack on the name of the app at the end of command. Without it I'm not actually updating the right models. so it should have been (main = AppName):

```
python manage.py syncdb main
python manage.py makemigrations main
python manage.py migrate main
```

That solved my issue! Thanks Paulo for pointing me in the right direction!